# Removal of items from listbox not working properly

Tags: asp.net, listbox

When I click on the button(checkbox) all items in the listbox will get disappeared.How to prevent this??My remove function is not working properly.Is it because of my javascript? My code is as follows:

.aspx file

```
                    <tr>
                        <td width="150px">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"  onkeypress="displayKeyCode_demo(event)"></asp:TextBox>         
                        </td>
                        <td width="200px">
<asp:ListBox ID="LstScan" runat="server" Height="200px" Width="150px"  >
                            </asp:ListBox>

                             <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hdnScan"/>
                        </td>

                        <td width="100px">
                            <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Remove" OnClientClick="removeItem()" />
                        </td></tr></table>






 javascript:

    <script type="text/javascript">
            function displayKeyCode_demo(e) {
                var code;
                if (!e) var e = window.event;
                if (e.keyCode) code = e.keyCode;
                else if (e.which) code = e.which;
                if (code == 13) {

                    var ListBox = document.getElementById("<%=LstScan.ClientID%>");
                    var TextBox = document.getElementById("<%=TextBox1.ClientID%>");
                    var hdnScan = document.getElementById("<%=hdnScan.ClientID%>");
                var myOption = new Option();
                myOption.text = document.getElementById("<%=TextBox1.ClientID%>").value.trim(); //Textbox's value
                myOption.value = document.getElementById("<%=TextBox1.ClientID%>").value.trim(); //Textbox's value
                hdnScan.value = hdnScan.value + "," + TextBox.value;
                ListBox.appendChild(myOption);
                document.getElementById("<%=TextBox1.ClientID%>").value = '';

//                e.preventDefault();
            }
      }
      function removeItem() {
//          var i;
//          var selectbox = document.getElementById("<%=LstScan.ClientID%>");
//          for (i = selectbox.options.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
//              if (selectbox.options[i].selected)
//                  selectbox.remove(i);
          //          }
          document.getElementById("<%=LstScan.ClientID%>").options[document.getElementById("<%=LstScan.ClientID%>").selectedIndex] = null;
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this code

```
function removeItem()
{
   document.getElementById('<% = LstScan.ClientID %>').options.length = 0;
}
```

Comment: I assume that the main problem is not that the `removeItem` is not working but that _"all items in the listbox disappear"_ on postback which is normal when an element is created on clientside.

Comment: how to retain values in listbox on postback.

Answer (score 0):

**Using jQuery:**

**To remove all options:**

```
$('<%=LstScan.ClientID%>').empty();
```

Refer - [.empty()](http://api.jquery.com/remove/)

**To remove particular option:**

```
$('OPTION[VALUE="valueofOption"]', $("<%=LstScan.ClientID%>")).remove();
```

Refer - [.remove()](http://api.jquery.com/remove/)